# Doom Emacs lsp-ui action hotkeys

Tags: emacs

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to emacs. I recently installed Doom emacs and I've been really enjoying it. One thing that I'm struggling to find out is how do I quickly access/select on of the actions that are given to me by lsp-mode (I assume it's lsp-ui). I've attached a screenshot - the actions that I'm referring to are on the right-hand side.

[image]

Quick side questions:

1. When I jump to definition (spc-c-d) how do I jump back? Do I just kill the buffer?
2. Using ivy, how can I easily go through the list? - using control-n is a bit hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can come back to the previous buffer using `CTRL+O`
2. You can go down or up in the list using `CTRL+j` or `CTRL+k`

Answer (score 0):

There are some tricks to get the answer:

- first, try to find the action or function you know.

  example 1. "M-x action-you-want-to-know"
  [image]

  example 2. "C-h k then-type-the-shortcut-key-you-want-to-search"
  [image]
- second, try to get the answer from project issues
  [image]

---

The answer to your question:

1: press "C-o" jump backward

2: Try to input multi keywords in your search field to narrow down the search scope, just like increment search.
If you get too many lines after ivy-search some keyword you input, that means you donot know what you want to search, right?